# laravel-mongodb increment with nested object

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5, jenssegers-mongodb

I have a post documents that schema looks like

```
    {
        "author": {
            "name": "John",
            "gender": 0
        },
        "stats": {
            "likes": 0
        },
        "content": "The new post",
        "updated_at": "2017-06-05 15:15:21",
        "created_at": "2017-06-04 18:10:30",
    }
```

How can I update the `stats.likes` field through `jenssegers/laravel-mongodb`

According to the GitHub page, There are a method `increment()` that can be used. 
So I was trying this way

```
Post::findOrFail( $request->id )->increment('stats.likes');
```

But got

```
ErrorException in HasAttributes.php line 906:
Undefined index: stats.likes
```

However, with the mongo shell, it can work at the code

```
db.posts.update( { '_id': ObjectId('5933dc7d4abcf141956a6250') }, { '$inc': { 'stats.likes': 1 } )  )
```

Is that an error caused by nested object?

According to the source code, I found

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function increment($column, $amount = 1, array $extra = [], array $options = [])
{
    $query = ['$inc' => [$column => $amount]];

    if (! empty($extra)) {
        $query['$set'] = $extra;
    }

    // Protect
    $this->where(function ($query) use ($column) {
        $query->where($column, 'exists', false);

        $query->orWhereNotNull($column);
    });

    return $this->performUpdate($query, $options);
}
```

If I'm not wrong, the field name `stats.likes` will pass to the shell directly at the 1st parameter of the method. Why it can just work with the command line?

- MongoDB 3.4
- jenssegers/laravel-mongodb 3.2
- Laravel 5.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I can update a nested object through the artisan command, I wrote a raw expression below alternatively:

```
$result = Post::raw(function($collection) use ($request){

    return $collection->findOneAndUpdate([
        '_id' => new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID ($request->_id),
    ], [ '$inc' => [ 'stats.likes' => 1 ] ] );

});
```

Notice that you may have effect with `db.articles.update()`, but the `Mongo\Collection` doesn't have a method named `update()`, use `findOneAndUpdate`, or others instead. (`UpdateMany`, `UpdateOne`)

And if the where condition contains `_id`, you have to wrap your id variable with `\MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID` object in the case of raw expression.